# Very high latency running Python Flask app on gcloud app engine

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, gcloud, flask-restful

I have this small Python Flask app that gets a file posted as input and runs this file through a tensforflow keras model to come back with a prediction.

On my old laptop, running this locally it is superfast. The app consumes around 450MB or ram.

Now I have deployed this app to gcloud app engine, and I experience extremely high lantency, ranging from 1,900 to 3,500 ms. 1000x slower than on my own laptop! Not only is it slow, but it starts to much instances as well because of it.

I have tried with F2 and F4 instances (F1 doesn't provide enough memory), but it doesn't make a difference.

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python37
env: standard
instance_class: F2
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, abort
from firebase import verifyToken, log
from model_manager import predict
import werkzeug, os
import tempfile

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
api = Api(app)

post_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
post_args.add_argument('file', type=werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage, location='files', help="No file provided.", required=True)
post_args.add_argument('Authorization', type=str, location='headers', help="No auth token provided.", required=True)

class Analyze(Resource):
    def post(self):
        data = post_args.parse_args()

        if not verifyToken(data['Authorization']):
            abort(401, message="The user is not authorized to use this ")

        try:
            tf = os.path.join('tmp', tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile().name)
            data['file'].save(tf)
            result = predict(tf)
        except Exception as ex:
            abort(400, message=ex)
        finally:
            if tf:
                os.remove(tf)

        return result, 200

api.add_resource(Analyze, "/")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Am I doing something wrong here that causes the high latency?

Comment: Are you reloading your model for every request?

Comment: The model is loaded with the instance. As long as the instance is life, the model stays loaded and is not loaded again. The load_model is outside of any function.

Comment: I have no disabled the model and just return a fixed result, also disabled the firebase part, the file write part. I get the same latency.

Comment: Isn't it like that the file on your local machine, so when you run locally you do not have to download it?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use tensorflow serving . Read https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/serving for more detail .